# Can Apple give an option to check cellular data usage for every bill cycle?

Tags: ios, cellular-data, data

How can i find on iphone 11 pro the cellular data usage for every bill cycle?

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to bmike's answer, this may be entirely provider-dependant.

On O2 UK, I have no option to view my usage per bill cycle, only since last manual reset. My provider has an app to view usage [& many other provider options].

The Euro-equivalent to 'Cellular', Mobile Data show the overall usage since last reset, plus a long list of usage per app below.
It is not tied to the provider's billing cycle at all.

I do, btw, have my provider's profile correctly installed; this is not a configuration error. The blue 'Network Provider Services' links through to their home page, for those who don't have their app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not all carriers feed the data, but Apple provides two methods to interact with traditional cellular services:

- sms short codes
- cellular item in the settings app via structured data exchange

Not all carriers send the data to the device, so not all phones will show what the iOS is capable of showing.

[image]

I prefer seeing the data and dates - so tap settings, tap cellular, tap usage.

[image]

You can see much of the data one screen prior to the detailed settings that show precisely when the carrier reports a billing cycle ends. Of course, Apple just is the conduit - you should reach out to your carrier to understand if they take advantage of Apple’s standard interface or require you to use a custom app or sending SMS short codes or get your usage data in some other non-standard manner.

Comment: Is that directly under the top level, green icon looks a bit like (( | )) ? UK that's labelled 'Mobile Data' & the contents are totally different. No billing period is shown either, just 'since last reset' so you have to remember to reset it manually if it's to be of any use. My carrier [O2] has its own App for that type of data.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin feel free to add an answer / edit mine. I almost put in a second screen shot showing the intermediate screen. The good news is iOS will update if the carrier pushes that data - I am on fully automatic - I don’t have to reset anything and my device accurately tracks each month per the correct billing cycle. I know not all carriers do that, though.

Comment: I dropped in a 2nd answer, though it's a bit hand-wavy as I can't say if this is the same for all UK providers, this being the only one I've used in the past decade or so.

Comment: Interesting. This seems to be provider-specific, I don't see these details in Settings (my screen looks more like the one @Tetsujin included in his answer).

Comment: This is indeed carrier-specific, made available by the carrier over the network with availability declared by the carrier bundle. bmike is on T-Mobile, and TMobile_US.bundle’s carrier.plist has `CarrierSpace.Supports{Plans,Usage}` set to true. This isn’t available for me/@Tetsujin on O2.

Comment: @grg - I can see the benefit of a 3rd, combined information answer here; especially as you have info even on what plist 'tag' it needs to enable it.